# Electron - ERROR:print_render_frame_helper.cc(2224) Printing failed

Tags: printing, electron

I have no idea what is happening here, basically I tried to print a document in electron using webContents.print, by silent print, but this error occurs and the printer only prints the document a single time, after that the print queue is filled with new orders, but the error still happening and the file is not printed.

Some code of what I am trying to do:

```
ipcMain.handle('imprimir', async (event, args) => {
  console.log(args);
  const ticket = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  });


  ticket.loadFile('src/views/ticket.html')
    .then(() => {

      ticket.webContents.send('enviar-pedido', args);

      var options = {
        silent: true,
        deviceName: 'HP Deskjet 2000 J210 series',
        printBackground: true,
        color: false,
        margin: {
          marginType: 'printableArea'
        },
        landscape: false,
        pagesPerSheet: 1,
        collate: false,
        copies: 1,
        /*pageSize: { height: 600, width: 353 }*/
      }

      ticket.webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => {
        if (!success) {
          console.log(failureReason);
        }

        console.log('Print Initiated');

        ticket.close();
      });
    });
```

Note: I do not speak fluent English and this is my first question here, I am sorry if I commited some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this just the other day.
I determined the error does not appear with the BrowserWindow option

```js
nodeIntegration: false
```

If you do not need `nodeIntegration` in the HTML loaded into the ticket window you should be able to turn this off.